# How to make all static files like css/images/js files not be processed by asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible that static files not be processed by the asp.net mvc engine?

Can I do this at the IIS level or something? (without ofcourse creating a seperate IIS website for static files)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to create an ignore route for the specific types of files you don't want to be served through ASP.NET MVC.

Add the following to your routes, for the types of files you want to ignore.

The following works for files in the root:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.css");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.jpg");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.gif");
```

If you want to ignore files in a specific directory, you can do this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("assets/{*pathInfo}");
```

If you want to combine these into one route, you can (e.g., ignore specific types of files in a directory):

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{assets}", new { assets = @".*\.(css|js|gif|jpg)(/.)?" });
```

This [overload of `IgnoreRoute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470170(v=vs.118).aspx) accepts a url (the first argument) and a Constraints object of things to ignore.

Since the RouteConstraints in ASP.NET MVC can be implemented multiple ways (including a regex), you can put standard regexes in the second argument.

If you want to implement a custom constraint, [there is lots of useful documentation on that subject](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs) (say, if your constraint is dynamic at runtime).

Comment: Why can you just do routes.RouteExistingFiles = false; Should not it be working for files that do exist?

Answer (score 22):

Be careful, @george-stocker's answer works for static files **in the root directory only!!!**

To catch static files in all possible directories/subdirectories, use an ignore rule with a "condition", like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allfiles}", new { allfiles = @".*\.(css|js|gif|jpg|png)" });
```

Comment: The question was ambiguous, but to me ignoring by file extension tends to  imply you want to do this globally (including subdirectories). This answer accomplishes that whereas accepted answer does not.

Answer (score 9):

Static files are not processed by ASP.NET MVC, unless you have a route that matches the URL of a static file. Maybe you are asking about static files processed by ASP.NET, in that case you should not use `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"`. Here's a [post](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html) with more info.

Answer (score 3):

In `Global.asax.cs` in the beginning of method `RegisterRoutes` write the following:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
```

replacing `Content` with the name of a folder containing your static files.

George, however, provided [More comprehensive solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715934/how-to-make-all-static-files-like-css-images-js-files-not-be-processed-by-asp-net/7715945#7715945)